# What does the Gold Badge next to a name on a duplicate post notice mean?

Tags: support, closed-questions, moderation

Recently, I found this when I was editing:
[image: marked as duplicate by grgarside]
What does the gold circle in the shape of a badge mean? Gold Badges don't appear on all marked as duplicate post notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a tag badge. There is a silver, gold and bronze tag badge. You get one for each tag depending on the score you earn on each. For example. a gold osx badge shows this gold badge symbol when marking as duplicate. It gives the user elevated privileges to better handle tag moderation.

- [Add gold tag badge privileges to a user's Privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254765/add-gold-tag-badge-privileges-to-a-users-privileges-page)